# no matches for kind "PrometheusRule" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1" when install RabbitMQ HA using helm

Tags: kubernetes

When I using helm v3.2.1 to install RabbitMQ HA in kubernetes v1.15.2 cluster follow by [this manual](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/rabbitmq-ha):

```
./helm install stable/rabbitmq-ha --generate-name -n dabai-pro
```

it give me this tips:

```
[miao@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm install stable/rabbitmq-ha --generate-name -n dabai-pro
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "PrometheusRule" in version "monitoring.coreos.com/v1"
```

should I install some dependencies? what should I do to make it work? This is my helm version detail info:

```
[miao@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.1", GitCommit:"fe51cd1e31e6a202cba7dead9552a6d418ded79a", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.10"}
```

and this is the repo I am using now:

```
[miao@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm repo list
NAME    URL
stable  https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [Prometheus operator](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator) in the cluster. RabbitMQ is monitored by Prometheus.After installation verify by running below command

```
kubectl api-resources | grep prom
prometheuses                                   monitoring.coreos.com          true         Prometheus
prometheusrules                                monitoring.coreos.com          true         PrometheusRule
```

For different installation options(including helm) of Prometheus check [this](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator#prometheus-operator-vs-kube-prometheus-vs-community-helm-chart)

Comment: And if I really don't wanna install the Prometheus operator, what do I do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like setting `prometheus.operator.enabled=false` doesn't require Prometheus installation.

I ran this:

```sh
helm install --set existingConfigMap=true,prometheus.operator.enabled=false rabbit-ha stable/rabbitmq-ha
```

And the chart successfully installed.